# First order matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Lets consider the differential equation, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial {x_n}}=A_n y$.

Where, $y$ is an $m$ dimensional column vector and, $A_n$ are $m\times m$ matrices that depends on $x_1,...,x_n$.

Is it correct to say that

$y=C\exp\left(\int A\right)$? Where A is a differential form defined as, $A=A_1 dx^1+.....+A_n dx^n$?
Where. $C$ is some constant.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to differentiate and see if it's $A_ny$?

Comment: When I differentiate I get $y A_n$ instead of $A_n y$. Not 100% sure if it's correct or not. It does not make sense though.

Comment: what is $yA_n$  though? The dimension does not match.

Comment: Do is it, $A_n y$ ? and the expression I wrote correct?

Comment: The more I think of it, I also wonder what is $\int A$.....

Comment: I think it should be more like $y=C exp(\int A) y_0$ Where  $A$ is one form and $y_0$ is a column vector. $y_0$ is the initial value.

Comment: When you integrate a one form you integrate along a curve. So which curve are you using?